# Parse/Swift Issue with tableviewcell "binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type cell and nil"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, uitableview

I've an issue with Parse/Swift using Xcode 6.3 beta

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath , object: PFObject) -> PFTableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! secTableViewCell

        if cell == nil
        {
            cell = secTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default , reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }
        // Configure the cell...

        cell.title.text = (object["exams"] as! String)
        cell.img.image = UIImage(named: "109.png")

        return cell
    }
```

The Error pointed to

```
 if cell == nil
        {
            cell = secTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default , reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }
```

binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type cell and nil"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`cell` is of type `secTableViewCell` not `secTableViewCell?` (`Optional<secTableViewCell>`). Because it's not an optional, it cannot be nil.

If you need to test for `nil`, then you want to have

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? secTableViewCell
```

The thing is you should never have to test for `nil`. "cell" should always be the same type (in your case it should alway be `secTableViewCell`.